# LaTeX for WordPress strips codes in loop

Tags: templates, latex

Installed [LaTeX for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latex/) and added post:

> Some text $$\alpha+\beta\geq\gamma$$ other text.

I see that equation in post page, but it stripped in loop.

How can I see equation in loop too?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about that plugin but it [applies filters to both `the_content` and `the_excerpt`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/latex/trunk/latex.php#L136), which seems reasonable to me. I have to assume that your theme is bypassing those filters somehow in the index listing. I can only guess at what it is doing, but you could add a filter to `get_the_content` and `get_the_exceprt` as well and that *might* help (but no guarantees).

```
// in functions.php, at least for testing
$latex_object = new latex_for_wp;
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', array($latex_object, 'parseTex'), 10001);
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', array($latex_object, 'parseTex'), 10001);
```

If that doesn't work I'd need to see what your theme is doing.

It is also possible that some other plugin is interfering.